# Why does it show load_1m, 5m, 15m when looking up nodes in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

[image]

There are columns called load_1m, 5m, and 15m when searching for nodes in Elasticsearch.

Usually only one load is indicated, but is there any reason to divide it into three?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is average of performance load for specific time period. You can refer [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-nodes.html) documentation.

Below is what mentioned in Elasticsarch documentation:

> **load_1m:** Most recent load average, such as 0.22.
>
> **load_5m:** Load average for the last five minutes, such as 0.78.
>
> **load_15m:** Load average for the last fifteen minutes, such as 1.24.

Comment: I know what that means.
I wonder why it was divided into such units.

Comment: it is devided to show just analytics of performance for specific internal. Because sometime what happen is that, for specific minitues it will be very high but if you average out for 5 min or 15 min then it will be normal. So it will help you to understand how your node is handling load.

Comment: But what does the value mean? Is it percentage? Then how can it be 1.24?

Comment: @hijack You can check https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/load-average-in-linux this document to know more about what is load average and how it is calculate.